# Prove that MGF is differentiable at everywhere? and $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log M(s)}{s} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

I am reading the some notes on probability theory and the
[notes(Chernoff lower bound)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec19.pdf) left some gap that I should fill in, however I don't even know how to start yet. Here is the assumption the gives by the notes:

1.$M(s)= E[e^{sX}]<\infty$  $ \forall s \in R  $

2.The random variable X is continuous, with $PDF$  $f_{X}$.

3.The random variable X does not admit finite upper and lower bounds ( Formally, $0<F_{X}<1$, for all $x\in R$)

The the note claim that:

a) $\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log M(s)}{s} = \infty$

b) $M(s) $ is differentiable at every $s$

how the assumption related to these claims , any hint for how to start ?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Please refrain from re-posting your questions.

Comment: @saz sorry... I just want more people to see it , and get some help ,won't do it again...